# Object variable or With block variable not set (Arrays)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

For several projects now I've had this error flash up and completely ground my projects. In most cases, I've simply had to leave them and start a new, different one. Basically, I just want to be able to refer to every object on the form that matches certain criteria. In this case it's an arcade style game with four different game modes. There is a timer that creates the objects to be shot at and it works fine, either a PictureBox or a label depending on which mode. on creation it changes the tag of each object to "Obj" & *whatever shape/maths number it is* with a space in-between. But for some reason it won't create an array of sorts on a different timer tick event to move them.

I just need it to be able to constantly add and delete objects to shoot at, the adding and moving and deleting was working fine, but as in all my other cases with arrays this error just worms its way in and me and my seriously qualified IPT teacher can't figure it out. Why does it suddenly start doing it and how can I fix it? Attached is some of the code for the object move event.

```
Dim NumofObjsLeft As Integer = 0
    For Each obj As Object In Me.Controls
        If obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
            NumofObjsLeft += 1
            If NumofObjsLeft <= 0 Then
                Wav += 1
                WaveStart = True
            End If
            Select Case GameMode
                Case "Protector"
                    Select Case Curry
                        Case "Shapes"
                            If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Left += 15
                            End If
                        Case "Maths"
                            If TypeOf obj Is Label AndAlso obj.tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Left += 15
                            End If
                    End Select
```

EDIT: Just thought I'd add all the code for Shape Spawn and Move. I haven't finished the other half of the code for Shape Move cause I couldn't get the first part to work.

```
Private Sub tmrShapeSpawn_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrShapeSpawn.Tick
    If WaveStart = True Then
        Select Case Wav
            Case 1
                NumofObjs = Wave1
            Case 2
                NumofObjs = Wave2
            Case 3
                NumofObjs = Wave3
            Case 4
                NumofObjs = Wave4
            Case 5
                NumofObjs = Wave5
            Case 6
                NumofObjs = Wave6
        End Select
        If F < NumofObjs Then
            Dim newPic As PictureBox = New PictureBox
            Dim newLab As Label = New Label
            Dim CorrectLabel As Label = New Label
            Dim CorrectPictureBox As PictureBox = New PictureBox
            CorrectPictureBox.Height = 75
            CorrectPictureBox.Width = 100
            CorrectLabel.AutoSize = True
            CorrectLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            CorrectPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            CorrectPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            CorrectLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            CorrectLabel.Font = New Font("Goudy Stout", 60, FontStyle.Regular)
            Select Case GameMode
                Case "Protector"
                    Randomize()
                    If CorrectMade = False Then
                        CorrectLabel.Left = CorrectLabel.Width
                        CorrectPictureBox.Left = CorrectPictureBox.Width
                        CorrectLabel.Top = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Height - CorrectLabel.Height))
                        CorrectPictureBox.Top = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Height - CorrectPictureBox.Height))
                    End If
                    newLab.Left = newLab.Width
                    newPic.Left = newPic.Width
                    newLab.Top = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Height - newLab.Height))
                    newPic.Top = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Height - newPic.Height))
                Case "Catcher"
                    Randomize()
                    If CorrectMade = False Then
                        CorrectLabel.Top = CorrectLabel.Height
                        CorrectPictureBox.Top = CorrectPictureBox.Height
                        CorrectLabel.Left = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Width - CorrectLabel.Width))
                        CorrectPictureBox.Left = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Width - CorrectPictureBox.Width))
                    End If
                    newLab.Top = newLab.Height
                    newPic.Top = newPic.Height
                    newLab.Left = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Width - newLab.Width))
                    newPic.Left = Int(Rnd() * (Me.Width - newPic.Width))
            End Select
            Select Case Curry
                Case "Maths"
                    lblCriteria.Text = lstNum1.Items.Item(Wav - 1) & " " & lstOp.Items.Item(Wav - 1) & " " & lstNum2.Items.Item(Wav - 1) & " ="
                    If CorrectMade = False Then
                        CorrectLabel.Text = lstAns.Items.Item(Wav - 1)
                        CorrectLabel.Tag = "Obj " & lstAns.Items.Item(Wav - 1)
                        Me.Controls.Add(CorrectLabel)
                        CorrectLabel.BringToFront()
                    End If
                    Randomize()
                    newLab.Text = Int(Rnd() * 100)
                    newLab.Tag = "Obj " & newLab.Text
                    Me.Controls.Add(CorrectLabel)
                    CorrectLabel.BringToFront()
                Case "Shapes"
                    Dim epahs As Integer
                    Dim sap As String
                    lblCriteria.Text = lstShape.Items.Item(Wav - 1)
                    If CorrectMade = False Then
                        CorrectPictureBox.ImageLocation = "Shapes\" & lstShape.Items.Item(Wav - 1) & ".png"
                        CorrectPictureBox.Tag = "Obj " & lstShape.Items.Item(Wav - 1)
                        Me.Controls.Add(CorrectPictureBox)
                        CorrectPictureBox.BringToFront()
                    End If
                    Randomize()
                    epahs = Int(Rnd() * 9)
                    Select Case epahs
                        Case 0
                            sap = "Square"
                        Case 1
                            sap = "Circle"
                        Case 2
                            sap = "Triangle"
                        Case 3
                            sap = "Rectangle"
                        Case 4
                            sap = "Oval"
                        Case 5
                            sap = "Hexagon"
                        Case 6
                            sap = "Star"
                        Case 7
                            sap = "Diamond"
                        Case 8
                            sap = "Trapezium"
                        Case 9
                            sap = "Rhombus"
                    End Select
                    newPic.ImageLocation = "Shapes\" & sap & ".png"
                    newPic.Tag = "Obj " & sap
                    newPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                    Me.Controls.Add(newPic)
                    newPic.BringToFront()
            End Select
            CorrectMade = True
            F += 1
        Else
            WaveStart = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub tmrShapeMove_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrShapeMove.Tick
    Dim CBA As Integer
    Dim NumofObjsLeft As Integer = 0
    For Each obj As Object In Me.Controls
        If obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
            NumofObjsLeft += 1
            If NumofObjsLeft <= 0 Then
                Wav += 1
                WaveStart = True
            End If
            Select Case GameMode
                Case "Protector"
                    Select Case Curry
                        Case "Shapes"
                            If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Left += 15
                            End If
                        Case "Maths"
                            If TypeOf obj Is Label AndAlso obj.tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Left += 15
                            End If
                    End Select
                    For CBA = 0 To ABC Step 1
                        If Collision(obj, Missile(CBA)) Then
                            Missile(CBA).Visible = False
                            Missile(CBA).Enabled = False
                            If picExplosion1.Visible = True And picExplosion2.Visible = False And picExplosion3.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion2.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion2.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion2)
                            ElseIf picExplosion1.Visible = True And picExplosion2.Visible = True And picExplosion3.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion3.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion3.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion3)
                            ElseIf picExplosion1.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion1.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion1.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion1)
                            Else
                            End If
                            If obj.Tag.Contains(lblCriteria.Text) Then
                                lblScore.Text += 1
                            Else
                                lblLives.Text -= 1
                            End If
                            Me.Controls.Remove(obj)
                        End If
                    Next CBA
                Case "Catcher"
                    Select Case Curry
                        Case "Shapes"
                            If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Top += 15
                            End If
                        Case "Maths"
                            If TypeOf obj Is Label AndAlso obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                                obj.Top += 15
                            End If
                    End Select
                    If Collision(obj, picChar) Then
                        If obj.Tag.Contains(lblCriteria.Text) Then
                            Score += 1
                        Else
                            Lives -= 1
                        End If
                        Me.Controls.Remove(obj)
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
    Next obj

End Sub
```

Comment: Upon which line does the error appear?

Comment: The error is basically saying "this object doesn't exist anymore". It may not be the obj, but a property of the obj (like obj.Tag, or Me.Controls).

Comment: That error message is a VB6 error message, not VB.NET

Comment: @JamesThorpe. It appears on line three: "If obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then". However if I remove that condition it simly appears later.

Comment: Could you check if something is setting your obj.Tag to nothing, or test it isn't nothing before attempting a Contains call?

Comment: @Mort. Never thought of that. Thanks I'll give it a go, didn't think it'd throw up an error though.

Comment: @StingyJack. Sorry mate, no idea what a backgroundworker is. Righto thanks I'll try adding an if statement prior to the error. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1) Use [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of timer. Its built to interact correctly with the main form thread and handle control interactions a bit more cleanly. Timers are notoriously problematic for both main UI thread sync issues and exiting unexpectedly.

2) You have to handle the obj.Tag or obj being nothing. The easiest way is to add

```
If obj is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrWhitespace(obj.Tag) Then
 Continue For
End If
```

...as the first statement after the For loop.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I think I'll just use my way. i;'m sure using a background worker is better but it seems to be working for me now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Righto, thanks to everyone who commented, replied. It seems to be working now with just that extra condition. Adding an if statement to check to see if the tag is empty before comparing the text.

```
Dim NumofObjsLeft As Integer = 0
    For Each obj As Object In Me.Controls
        If obj.Tag > "" Then
            If obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                NumofObjsLeft += 1
                If NumofObjsLeft <= 0 Then
                    Wav += 1
                    WaveStart = True
                End If
                Select Case GameMode
                    Case "Protector"
                        Select Case Curry
ETC...................................................
```

Comment: The ' if obj.Tag > "" Then'  is not something you want to use in the future, especially if other programmers are going to help maintain the code.

Comment: Isn't that what StingyJack proposed? Also, his answer is better than doing a >